# Removal of images which OP himself uploaded as context.

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2740779/finding-the-roots-of-a-polynomial-of-the-form-w6-9kw418k2w2-6-k3),  OP initially uploaded a sequence of images which he initially said "were not so relevant".  Turns out that sequence shows where his problem comes from, and is a motivation which provides context to the question.

However, the sequence of images by itself provides nothing beyond that, in the sense that it is unrelated to the mathematical question. Because of that, I removed the images and put the text "I've found this polynomial while solving a problem related to a triple pendulum (for context, w is the frequency of a triple pendulum with equal lengths l; and g is gravity) and couldn't manage to proceed", in order to preserve the context.

Notice that there is also another fact which may be relevant: initially, the images were links. One edit turned them to embedded images. And then I removed them altogether and proceeded as above.

My questions are:

1. Did I make the right call? (If not, why?)
2. In general, if images provide context unrelated to the question per se, is it proper to remove them and substitute them for text?

Comment: In my opinion, you made the right call. I, too, have often removed images and replaced them with text describing the relevant parts from the image. It helps in searching, as well as clarity in viewing.

Comment: Text/mathjax is always preferable to images of the same.  About the only time where an image can be useful, and should likely stay, is when an asker has included an image of a graph, or a geometrical object, or other such visuals for which there is no reasonably simple way to use text and mathjax to represent.  In this case, I would have made the same call as you did.

Comment: You have removed too much, the image indicate the user has spent some effort to come up with something and the question is not a PSQ (and should not be downvoted b/c it is lacking context/effort). You should remove the image but keep links to those images as references.

Comment: No need to clutter up the question with a ton of tangentially related embedded images, but I see no problems leaving the links as supplementary information. The comments might be a better place than the question body, though.